# Does "map" container of C++ apply Rabin-Karp algorithm for consecutive substrings of a string?

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, hashtable, rabin-karp

I'm working on a code-plagiarism detection method. I need to use *fingerprint* algorithm for this method. Fingerprint algorithm puts all substrings of the source code to a hash table. (All substrings have same length.) For the purpose of optimization, it's recommended that using Rabin-Karp algorithm while putting the fingerprints to the hash table.

For example; for the string = *abcdef* and for the length = *5*, we should put *abcde* and *bcdef* substrings to the hash table. Since hashing of strings needs to apply a mathematical operation for each character of the string, it will be expensive for numerous substrings.

Rabin-Karp algorithm takes advantage of being consecutive of substrings. It calculates hash value of the first fingerprint. And for the rest of substrings, it uses the previous substring.

Does "map" container of C++ automatically apply this algorithm for consecutive substrings on the background? Or should I write my own hash library?

Comment: Look at the constructor. It looks like you can provide the hasher. I doubt there's any specification on the default.

Comment: Different implementations of `std::map` may use different algorithms. The standard does not specify what algorithm the C++ library should use. You can ask if a specific implementation of the C++ standard library use this specific algorithm. To be sure your implementation uses a specific algorithm, write your own. I doubt `std::map` uses such algorithm, `std::map` should be very generic, not only apply to strings.

Comment: `std::map` is *usually* implemented using a red-black tree... I don't see how such a special-case thing like you're describing would be applicable. Or are you thinking of `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Since the question is specifically about how the "hash" is implemented, I suspect you want the actual "hash table" data structure, std::unordered_map, which is the O(1) hash lookup. That's not what std::map does.

Comment: I didn't know the difference between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`. Thanks for suggestions. It seems that I should write my own hash library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for std::unordered_map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/ takes a hasher.

From online docs on std::hash (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above.